# Creating multiple subset dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am new to R (and programming in general) and am currently trying to figure out how to create multiple data frame subsets from a large file without having to use the `subset` function to create each individual data frame.  Here is an example.

Let's suppose I have a large list of football plays each designated by a number.  Then I list which positions (widereceivers, tight ends, etc.) are involved in each play, and then the resulting yardage.

How can I create an individual dataframe for each play (play1, play2, etc.) without copying and pasting an individual `subset` function for each play?  It gets pretty heavy when there are 100+ plays/game.  Here's a small sample chart:

```
Play    Play.des    result
1        WR1          -5
1        WR2          -5
1        OL           -5
1        WR3          -5
1        WR4          -5
1        RB           -5
1        QB           -5
2        WR1           7
2        WR2           7
2         OL           7
2        WR3           7
2        RB            7
2        RB            7
2        QB            7
3       WR1           24
3       WR2           24
3        OL           24
3       WR3           24
3       WR4           24
3        RB           24
3        QB           24
4       WR1           -2
4       TE            -2
4       OL            -2
4       TE            -2
4       WR4           -2
4       RB            -2
4       QB            -2
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `split` function as:

```
dfs <- split(df, unique(df$Play))

dfs$`1`

# Play Play.des result
# 1     1      WR1     -5
# 5     1      WR4     -5
# 9     2      WR2      7
# 13    2       RB      7
# 17    3       OL     24
# 21    3       QB     24
# 25    4       TE     -2

dfs$`2`

# Play Play.des result
# 2     1      WR2     -5
# 6     1       RB     -5
# 10    2       OL      7
# 14    2       QB      7
# 18    3      WR3     24
# 22    4      WR1     -2
# 26    4      WR4     -2

# Similarly 3rd and 4th can be accessed.
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Play    Play.des    result
1        WR1          -5
1        WR2          -5
1        OL           -5
1        WR3          -5
1        WR4          -5
1        RB           -5
1        QB           -5
2        WR1           7
2        WR2           7
2         OL           7
2        WR3           7
2        RB            7
2        RB            7
2        QB            7
3       WR1           24
3       WR2           24
3        OL           24
3       WR3           24
3       WR4           24
3        RB           24
3        QB           24
4       WR1           -2
4       TE            -2
4       OL            -2
4       TE            -2
4       WR4           -2
4       RB            -2
4       QB            -2",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: dont you mean `split(df, df$Play)`

Comment: Thank you both!  I was finally able to get it to work using your suggestions. I thought maybe I had to use split somehow, but couldn't get it quite right.  Thank you for taking the time to help a newbie!